# Mezuzah Case Materials?

Tags: mezuzah, protective-casing

I am looking into buying and installing Mezuzot on and in my home. I am wondering about the different materials available for the case, as I do not want to the outdoor mezuzot scrolls to go bad. Any suggestions for the out door ones? What do you use and how well did it hold up?

Comment: Many people wrap their scrolls in saran wrap to keep the moisture out. Regardless of what case they are put in

Comment: Yes, I mean the case, not the parchment.  Sorry I was not clear about that. I also read that wrapping in wax paper is better than any kind of plastic wrap because the parchment will sweat if wrapped in plastic.

Comment: @Aaron, I discovered when I was in Israel that wax paper is better. It's easier to prepare and is way less of a mess. FWIW, HaSofer uses it, as well as many American sofrim.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8714 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27831

Comment: Chabad custom ,based on the Baal Shem Tov, is to not use a metal mezzuzah case. Metal is seen as used for war which shortens life. The commandment of mezzuzah lengthens life. I am not sure if this includes silver, which could be ornamental and not used for war? Some mekubalim avoid leather as well

Comment: Good to know, David. I was leaning toward carved stone or pewter, but was not sure how weather-tight those would be. I resist using plastic because it seems cheap and artificial. I was told by a rabbi that when we buy mitzvot items (Tallis, Candlesticks, Kiddush cup, Mezuzot, etc), the better it is the more it honors G-d, and that it is a privilege to sacrifice financially for the best. That makes sense to me. Why skimp on those things and shell out $200 for  football tickets or $800 for custom wheels?

Comment: @LawrenceVoltz The money from the wheels and from the fancy mezuza case are probably better spent as a donation to poor (orphans, widows, etc.).

Comment: Yes, well, we can do both. The point is that we should not skimp on the things of God, be it charity or Judaica. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to the mezuzah case, rather than the mezuzah itself, I have heard from my sofer, [R' Melech Michaels](http://mezuzadepot.com) that the ideal outdoor case is either made out of lucite or white plastic, as these keep out a fair amount of moisture and do not conduct heat as well as some others. At my house, we have a ceramic case and the mezuzah is still kosher.

Comment: "At my house, we have a ceramic case and the mezuzah is still kosher." How long has it lasted without becoming invalid?

Comment: @DoubleAA, my parents bought the house in '97 and the case and klaf are at least that old.